# BeautifulSoup to find unofficial HTML tags/attributes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In my job we are using tags that we have created. One of the tags called can-edit and it looks like this in the code (for example):

```
<h1 can-edit="banner top text" class="mainText">some text</h1>
<h2 can-edit="banner bottom text" class="bottomText">some text</h2>
```

It could be inside any tag (img, p, h1, h2, div...).

What i wish to get is all the can-edit tags within a page, for example with the HTML above:

```
['banner top text', 'banner bottom text']
```

i've tried

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
can_edits = soup.find_all("can-edit")
```

But it not finding any.

Comment: Those are attributes, not tags.

Comment: Useful and relevant section of BS4 docs: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=attrs%3D#the-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> i've tried
>
> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
> can_edits = soup.find_all("can-edit")
> ```
>
> But it not finding any.

The reason that this does not work is because here you look for a *tag* with the name `can-edit`, so `<can-edit ...>`, and this thus does not work.

You can use the `find_all` function of the soup to find all tags with a certain attribute. For example:

```
soup.find_all(attrs={'can-edit': True})
```

So here we use the `attrs` parameter and pass it an attribute that says that we filter tags that have a `can-edit` *attribute*. This will give us a list of tags with a `can-edit` attribute (regardless the value). If we now want to obtain the *value* of that attribute, we can get the `['can-edit']` item of it, so we can write a list comprehension:

```
all_can_edit_attrs = [tag['can-edit']
                      for tag in soup.find_all(attrs={'can-edit': True})]
```

Or a full working version:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """<h1 can-edit="banner top text" class="mainText">some text</h1>
<h2 can-edit="banner bottom text" class="bottomText">some text</h2>"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

all_can_edit_attrs = [tag['can-edit']
                      for tag in soup.find_all(attrs={'can-edit': True})]
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Just needed to change `bs = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')`

Comment: @Kraki: well that depends on what type of xml/xhtml/html/... you want to parse, but indeed, the concept can be applied to any parser supported by BeautifulSoup :)